# Changing dd/mm/yyyy/ hh/mm/ss format to yyyymm in Hive

Tags: date, hive, timestamp, hiveql, impala

I'm using Hive at the moment. I have a column (column A) of strings which is in the following format `11/9/2009 0:00:00`. I'd like to extract the `yyyymm`. i.e. I'd like the above string to be `200909`. I've tried two different methods none of them worked.

I have tried to convert the string using two different methods

```
       concat(year(Column A),lpad(month(Column A),2,0))


       convert(datetime, Column A)
```

For the first row of code I'm receiving : NULL in all rows

For the second one I'm receiving :

> Encountered: DATETIME Expected: ALL, CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, DISTINCT,
>   EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, TRUNCATE, TRUE,
>   IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Answer (score 2):

Use `unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern)` to convert [given date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to seconds passed from 1970-01-01. Then use from_unixtime() to convert to [required format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
select  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( '11/9/2009 0:00:00','dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'), 'yyyyMM');
```

Result:

```
200909
```

Read also: [Impala data and time functions](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) and [Hive date functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions).

One more solution, works in Hive:

```
select  concat(regexp_extract('11/9/2009 0:00:00','(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{4})',3),lpad(regexp_extract('11/9/2009 0:00:00','(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{4})',2),2,0))
```

Comment: since it is a string not a datetime stamp the above will not work.

Comment: @Yags I cannot check on Impala. This definitely works in Hive

Comment: @ leftjoin '11/9/2009 0:00:00','dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' this is a string in my dataset. hence the results are null. Where as in yours it's datetime

Comment: The second works fine. Also, my below solution produces the same output. Thank you @leftjoin

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm trying to turn strings into YYYYMM I have to use the below, which worked for me:

```
      'concat(substr(Column A, instr(Column A, ' ')-4, 4),substr(Column A, instr(Column A, ' /')+1, 2))'
```